# Reference current RoleProvider instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, roleprovider

When inside an ASP.NET page, module or handler with an [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) present, how do I get a reference to the current [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) instance?

It's the provider used for authorization when the [IPrincipal.IsInRole(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole.aspx) method is called. By default, or from configuration, my provider seems to be a [SqlRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx) instance by an error given when I'm running the app.

I want to inspect the type of provider at runtime to provide feedback on which one is actually being used.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [static Roles class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) has a Provider property on it which you can use to reference the current provider.

```
Roles.Provider
```

and if you are using a custom RoleProvider, you can cast it in order to access custom functionality.

```
((MyCustomRoleProvider)Roles.Provider).AllYourRoleAreBelongToUs();
```

Comment: Thanks! That info helped me determine my role provider is actually 'WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider' instead of the expected 'System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider'. Whew! Cheers.