# Is an Authentication token available in Asp.Net Web Api controller?

Tags: rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication

I am following this article to authenticate users of a Web API service I'm writing :

http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/

This works just fine.

In summary, we use a custom action filter (that gets applied to all requests), that checks an encrypted request header to determine who the user is.

However, I also have code in my controller action methods that needs to know who the current user is. Rather than repeat the logic that has been executed in the ActionFilter, is there a way I can set a variable in the action filter and refer to that in the controller action method?

I have also seen it suggested that MessageHandler should be used rather than an actionFilter. Would that help in some way?

Essentially I need to somehow flag up who the current user is in the Filter code and be able to refer to that in my controller

Or am I way off here? Is ther a smarter way?
thanks

Comment: i simply don't understand why the question is flagged as off topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Principal and store it in Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

You can then access it in the Web Api controller with User.Identity

[This method works on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445232/12919).

Comment: these links are also useful :
http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/     and    
http://sixgun.co.uk/blog/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpRequestMessage` object has a Properties collection where you can add arbitrary state that you can access in your controller action.

You would use the same approach if you used a `HttpMessageHandler` instead of an `ActionFilter`.

Comment: Is there a more Security specific object that should be populated? Feels like there should  be something already in the framework for this? - thanks for your help

Comment: @ChrisCa  The Thinktecture guys have built a bunch of security extensions to Web API and they decode the auth and create a Princial to store in Thread.CurrentPrincipal.  See http://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/03/thinktecture-identitymodel-and-asp-net-web-api-the-messagehandler/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no build in mechanism to support this kind of security.

In our project, we use a custom token in the `Request.Headers` collection which we round-trip in all Web Api calls. We created a custom `ActionFilter` that operates on all non-GET requests. We extract the token from the `Request.Headers` and compare it to the token in our `IClaimsIdentity`, which is accessible through `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`